# Is it possible to deploy an ASP.NET Web Forms website without building

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Just wondering if it is possible to deploy an ASP.NET Web Forms website to AWS without building as I started maintaining a disordered project with too many errors and I'm almost new to ASP.NET.

Comment: If you are getting compiler errors, deploying this site in any way shape or form is a **bad** idea. The compiler is telling you your website **will** break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by adding your website in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you mean just moving all the files into the wwwroot folder?

Comment: No you can attach the application path with IIS website. there is no need to move files into WWW folder.